# Unable to save email attachment from outlook to local drive

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, pywin32

i have written the below code to save email attachment from outlook with specific subject but its throwing an error.

**Below is the code** :

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders('xyz.com').Folders("Inbox")
messages = inbox.Items
for msg in messages:
    if 'Subject' in msg.Subject:
       print(msg.Subject)
       if not os.path.exists('C:\xyz\reports'):
    for atch in msg.Attachments:
       atch.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd() + 'C:\xyz\reports' + atch.Filename)
```

Error msg **: (-2147352567, 'Exception occured.',(4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Cannot save the attachment. File name or directory name is not valid.' None, 0, -2147024773), None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
atch.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd() + 'H:\Atul\Save' + atch.Filename)
```

to

```
atch.SaveAsFile('H:\Atul\Save\' + atch.Filename)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry it worked, i have one more question suppose if i have multiples emails with same subject line and i need to pick the latest attachment , what line should i include in my code ?

Comment: Also i need to save the xlsx (attachment) file with T-1 business date so if today is 30th Nov then it should save the file name as xyz-29th nov 2022.xlsx and if 30th nov is monday then it should save xyz-27th nov 2022.xlsx

Comment: Cal message.Sort first to sort on ReceivedTime property and pick the first match (you can use mesages.Restrict or mesages.Find).

Comment: As for including the date in the file name, you would need to break Attachment.FileName into name and extension, add the date to the name, then combine the two back.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, for now i have used break statement at the end of my code so that it will break after the first match is found, here i am presuming its loops through the latest to oldest mail

Comment: how can we break attachment into name and extension, would you please share a sample ?

Comment: You might want to post a separate question for that. I don't use Python, so I can only give a general overview - read the Attachment.Filename property, find the position of "." - the string to the left is the name, and the one to the right is the extension. Convert the date to a suitable string, then concatenate filename + date + '.' + extension.